# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' -- beautifulsoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape cryptocurrency rates from google search results but encountering the error as noted in the title.

Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def cryptoPrice(crypto):
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + crypto + "price"

    req = requests.get(url)

    soupObject = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    element = soupObject.find("div", {"class": "card-section PZPZlf"}).find("div").find("span", {"class": 'pclqee'}).text

    return element


price = cryptoPrice('bitcoin')
print(price)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first try to print `soup` object and find manually the tag related to price and you can find associate value to it!

```
def cryptoPrice(crypto):
    url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + crypto + "price"
    req = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
    value=soup.find('div',class_="BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd").get_text()

    return value


price = cryptoPrice('ethereum')
price1 = cryptoPrice('bitcoin')
print(price)
print(price1)
```

Comment: It works now, weirdly enough, as I cannot find the class you used anywhere (which is likely my shortcoming). Even keeping that aside, how am I supposed to look through the soup object when it prints the entire webpage? Isn't using `inspect element` option the best choice?

Comment: Actually its dynamic page so it changes and `bs4` is static and only shows the static web page html so it might be possible `class` changes as per User but you can try it using `selenium` also

Comment: Seems like you were deriving your solution from a medium article, I saw the video linked there and that fortunately cleared up some things. And the dynamic and static relation makes sense now, thank you.